# Find consecutive subsequences in list in python

Tags: python

I have a list and I have to find consecutive sequences in that list.

For example if my list is `[1,2,3,5,7,8,9]` then code should return `[1,2,3]` and `[7,8,9]`

And if the list is `[3,5,6,7,8,10]` it should return `[5,6,7,8]`

Please suggest me something how I can code it to find the consecutive sub-sequences?

Comment: Have you tried writing some code?

Comment: Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
my_cons = [3,5,6,7,8,10]

end = len(my_cons)
curr = 0
longest_seq = 0
longests = []

while curr < end:
    tmp_curr = curr;
    while tmp_curr < end-1:
        if my_cons[tmp_curr] +1 == my_cons[tmp_curr+1]:
            tmp_curr += 1
        else:
            break
    if tmp_curr - curr > longest_seq:
        longest_seq = tmp_curr - curr
        longests = [my_cons[curr:tmp_curr+1]]
    elif tmp_curr - curr == longest_seq:
        longests.append(my_cons[curr:tmp_curr+1])
    curr = tmp_curr + 1

print (longests)
```